# unboundid ldap upgraded version from 1.1.3 to 3.1.1. ClassNotFoundException being thrown.

Tags: weblogic, classnotfoundexception, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I have recently upgraded our unboundid ldap jar version from 1.1.3 to 3.1.1. After the upgrade when I am deploying the app in weblogic, I am getting a ClassNotFoundException in the log. So far I have faced no issues in terms of functionality, but I am concerned is there any connection leakage is happeining underneath or not.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.DisconnectType
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
... 1 more
```

App package : WAR

Server : Weblogic 10.3.6

Comment: did you replace the jar file in the same folder? (WEB-INF/lib ?)
I've checked both versions, and they have that class.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue, using unboundid ldap 2.2.0 and Tomcat 7, with reference to ProtocolMessages instead of DisconnectType:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/unboundid/ldap/protocol/ProtocolMessages
```

The class was definitely present in the jar files. In my case, this error was a smokescreen. On initialization, the application experienced an error and failed to load; however, some ldap connection threads had already connected and did not get shut down properly. The orphaned threads continued to throw NoClassDefFoundError until I restarted the application server.